# Qt Creator - How To Enable a Floating IDE Layout?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, docking

I'm a long-time user of *Embarcadero C++Builder* peeking into *Qt Creator* (Ver. 4.4.0) at the moment, which seems to be well-suited for all kind of C++ development tasks and thus might be pretty productive.

Unfortunately there's one **major** drawback slowing me down significantly in comparision to *C++Builder*: I can't find any setting enabling the re-arrangement of *Qt Creator*'s default IDE layout, since it's just not mine.

Is it really the case, that such a classy-looking IDE won't have that kind of feature nearly every other major competitor has?

Maybe there's an undock setting I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** It is not possible to undock any panel or view in QtCreator 4.4.0. But some sort of re-arrangement of views is possible.

---

There are left and right panels enabling some customization:

- Choosing what is shown in the panel from a set of views (e.g., project structure or open files)
- Resizing panels horizontally
- Splitting a panel in two vertically thus adding another view
- Resizing sub-panels vertically (after the split)

Unfortunately, that's about all the customization of layout there is.